# How to find correlation coefficient if the joint distribution of $(X,Y)$ is given by $f_{X,Y}(x,y)=2$ for $0<y<x<1$

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables

I am confused on how to find this answer, and have been stuck for over 2 hours. I know that you first have to find the marginal pdfs of $x$ and $y$ by integrating. So for the marginal pdf of $x$ I got $2x$, and for the marginal pdf of $y$ I got $2-2y$.

From there I do not know how to get the expected values of $X$ and $Y$, because I am not sure how to set up the limits of integration for them. For the expected value of $X$, I integrated $x*2x$ from $y$ to $1$ and got $\frac23-\frac23 y^3$... This is what's confusing me. You don't get an actual number for the expected value of $x$, which is part of what I need to solve for the correlation coefficient.

Comment: What do you mean by "I integrated x2x"?  Do you mean $x\cdot 2x$ or $x^2x$?

Comment: x * 2x, since the the the expected value of x = the integral from y to 1 of x * fX(x) dx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The marginal probability density of $X$ is $f_X(x)=2x, \ 0\leq x\leq 1$

You see $x$ is not limited by $y$. The range of $x$ is independent from $y$.

Thus $E(x)=\int_0^1 x\cdot f_X(x)\, dx =\int_0^1 x\cdot 2x\, dx$

Also $E(y)=\int_0^1 y\cdot f_Y(y)\, dx =\int_0^1 y\cdot (2-2y)\, dy$

Comment: Ok thanks, that helps a little. Just curious though, would writing 0<x<1 and 0<y<1 be the same as 0<x<y<1 and 0<y<x<1? Just kind of confused on that because it seems as if the bounds are saying that x has to be a greater value than y. And btw, how would you do the expected value of y and x together... like the E(x,y)???

Comment: @Luke No they are not the same.  But for the marginal probability density of $X$, x goes from 0 to 1. For the domain of x, y doesn´t play a role-but for the calculation of the marginal probability density (like you did). You can ask a new question for the calculation or $E(X,Y)$.